# Fatal Stackoverflow in running Flask Application

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting a fatal: stackoverflow error in my flask application. It is happening in a specific function, but seems to be pointing to the app.run statement. The function that contains the error is this:

```
@login_required
@flask_app.route('/newgame', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def newGame():
    user = current_user
    game_form = NewBetForm()
    if game_form.is_submitted():
        player = user.address
        privKey = user.privKey
        ethPwd = user.ethPwd
        amt = game_form.amount.data
        team_name = game_form.teamName.data
        player2 = game_form.player2.data
        player2team = game_form.player2Team.data
        user2 = dbsession.query(User).filter_by(username=player2).first()
        try:
            contract = createBet(player,user2.address,amt,privKey,ethPwd)
            contract.functions.createPlayer(w3.toChecksumAddress(player),amt,team_name).call()
            game = Game(player1=player,player1_team=team_name,
                    player2_team=player2team,addr=contract.address,active=True,amount=amt)
            invite = Invite(player1_from=user,player2_to=user2,game_id=game,amount=amt,team=player2team)
            dbsession.add(invite)
            dbsession.commit()
            dbsession.add(game)
            dbsession.commit()
            flash("Successfully entered bet game")
            return redirect(url_for('viewGame', game_id=game.id))
        except:
            flash("There was an issue with this bet. Please try again")
            return redirect(url_for('newGame'))
    return render_template('games/new_game.html', form=game_form)
```

The last line of the error that I'm getting (full stack trace will be later in this post) is this:

`File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943 in run
  File "app.py", line 6 in <module>`

Which is where I see it is pointing to the app.run statement on line 6 of the app.py file:

`flask_app.run(debug=True,host='localhost',threaded=True,port=port)`

I'm not sure where the error is actually occurring - it would not make sense to me that run statement would cause a stackoverflow error. Below is the full error trace:

```
Current thread 0x0000700000a04000 (most recent call first):
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 406 in trunc
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 521 in <genexpr>
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 521 in _repr_params
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 484 in __repr__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/exc.py", line 352 in _sql_message
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/exc.py", line 76 in __str__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 294 in _assert_active
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 407 in _connection_for_bind
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1129 in _connection_for_bind
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1123 in connection
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3286 in _connection_from_session
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3308 in _get_bind_args
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3293 in _execute_and_instances
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3271 in __iter__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3198 in one_or_none
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3229 in one
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 282 in load_on_pk_identity
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 208 in load_on_ident
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 979 in load_scalar_attributes
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 660 in _load_expired
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 182 in get_from_identity
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 987 in _identity_lookup
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1012 in _get_impl
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 933 in get
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/Documents/newbet/app/pyapp/models.py", line 48 in load_user
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 321 in reload_user
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 359 in _load_user
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 335 in _get_user
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 26 in <lambda>
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306 in _get_current_object
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 321 in __repr__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 406 in trunc
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 521 in <genexpr>
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 521 in _repr_params
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 484 in __repr__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/exc.py", line 352 in _sql_message
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/exc.py", line 76 in __str__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 294 in _assert_active
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 407 in _connection_for_bind
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1129 in _connection_for_bind
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1123 in connection
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3286 in _connection_from_session
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3308 in _get_bind_args
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3293 in _execute_and_instances
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3271 in __iter__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3198 in one_or_none
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3229 in one
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 282 in load_on_pk_identity
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 208 in load_on_ident
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 979 in load_scalar_attributes
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 660 in _load_expired
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 677 in get
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 276 in __get__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/Documents/newbet/app/pyapp/models.py", line 38 in __repr__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 406 in trunc
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 521 in <genexpr>
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 521 in _repr_params
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 484 in __repr__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/exc.py", line 352 in _sql_message
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/exc.py", line 76 in __str__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 294 in _assert_active
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 407 in _connection_for_bind
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1129 in _connection_for_bind
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1123 in connection
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3286 in _connection_from_session
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3308 in _get_bind_args
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3293 in _execute_and_instances
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3271 in __iter__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3198 in one_or_none
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3229 in one
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 282 in load_on_pk_identity
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 208 in load_on_ident
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 979 in load_scalar_attributes
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/state.py", line 660 in _load_expired
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py", line 182 in get_from_identity
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 987 in _identity_lookup
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 1012 in _get_impl
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 933 in get
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/Documents/newbet/app/pyapp/models.py", line 48 in load_user
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 321 in reload_user
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/login_manager.py", line 359 in _load_user
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 335 in _get_user
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 26 in <lambda>
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 306 in _get_current_object
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 321 in __repr__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 406 in trunc
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 521 in <genexpr>
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 521 in _repr_params
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/util.py", line 484 in __repr__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/exc.py", line 352 in _sql_message
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/exc.py", line 76 in __str__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 294 in _assert_active
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 407 in _connection_for_bind
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1129 in _connection_for_bind
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1123 in connection
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3286 in _connection_from_session
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3308 in _get_bind_args
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3293 in _execute_and_instances
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3271 in __iter__
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3198 in one_or_none
```

...

```
Thread 0x0000700000501000 (most recent call first):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/selectors.py", line 376 in select
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 236 in serve_forever
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 612 in serve_forever
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 777 in inner
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864 in run
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916 in _bootstrap_inner
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 884 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00007fff754cd000 (most recent call first):
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 164 in run
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 273 in run_with_reloader
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 812 in run_simple
File "/Users/pasquarella4292/.local/share/virtualenvs/newbet-EG4I_zLE/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943 in run
File "app.py", line 6 in <module>
```

**EDIT**

showing load_user method:

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return dbsession.query(User).get(int(id))
```

Comment: Show the `load_user` method in your models.py

Comment: It's also getting in to `__repr__` below that. Please show that, too.

Comment: ... generally it's a good idea to take a close look at any of your code that ends up on the stack trace.

Comment: correct. i'm running through and commenting out lines to narrow it down. it seems that the load_user method causes a problem here. the bets go through, but on adding the game to the database, i get a _str_ object has no attribute _sa_instance_state on the load_user method.

Comment: figured it out. the game object i was creating was referencing the wrong type for the player1 relationship. why this would cause a stackoverflow error does not quite make sense to me.